# Custom Action Group does not appear in ribbon

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, custom-action

I have implemented a custom action group in SharePoint from below code:

```
 <CustomActionGroup Id="Ribbon.Documents.CustomGroup"
                         Description="$Resources:bipDMSTemplate,grpCustomActionGroupDescription;"
                         Title="$Resources:bipDMSTemplate,grpCustomActionGroupName;"
                         Location="Ribbon.Library.Groups._children"
                         Sequence="100">
    </CustomActionGroup>
```

After deployment, the custom action group is not visible in `Ribbon.Library`.

What can the issue be?

Comment: Have you added any custom action in custom action group.

Comment: Is that possible only blank custom action group add in share point ribbon ?

Comment: Updated one article in my answer , you can refer it for clear picture about it.

Comment: @BhaskarDhone I can get your answer. but  i have a question. if i want to add three custom action in ribbon , thani have to create three group for that ?

Comment: Not required. You just to provide created group id to your custom action.

Comment: Ok . I'll get back to u if i have any query , Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33959/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-bhaskar-dhone).

Answer (score 2):

Custom action groups uses for creating groups not in ribbon, but in sharepoint pages, for example in site settings. If you want to create group in ribbon with button or other controls, you should provide three required CommandUIDefinition- GroupTemplate, Scaling and Group with controls.

You can refer this [article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html) for clear understanding.